# unable to find the cookie value returned by the server in chrome dev tool

Tags: performance, groovy, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to understand the source of thie cookie values.
1st image -> first request/ response
2nd image -> second request / response

The first response has no cookies. And the second request is sending cookies in request header. What is the source of this???

[index.html-> first request in chrome dev tool[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl5Fr.png)

[second request -> see the request header; these values arent recieved during the first response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAVek.png)